# Cannot import name x from y

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, module

Hello I am a complete python noob, I have been learning for about a week and im trying to complete a challenge from a tutorial but I have hit a complete brick wall and ive tried googling this but no solution for this type of error has worked for me. I am trying to import a module and get it to run at this certain point, but I get the error  cannot import name 'rock_paper_scissors' from 'rps8'.

```
from rps8 import rock_paper_scissors


  def choosegame():

    Playerschoice = (1, 2)

    print("Welcome to the arcade! \n")
    input("Please choose a game:\n1 = Rock Paper Scissors\n2 = Guess My Number\n")

    if Playerschoice == 1:
        rock_paper_scissors()
```

I was expecting for my rock paper scissors game from another module to start running once i entered 1 but i just get the error

Comment: Can you share your project's file structure?

Comment: How do i do that ? sorry im a complete noob

Comment: Is `rps8` a directory or a python module? Is it alongside the python module that you've shared its code with us?

Comment: it is a module and it is in the same folder as the module of the code i shared

Comment: So it should work. Add an screenshot of what you see in the vscode and put it in your question box.

Comment: Stackoverflow wont allow me to upload a screenshot because i dont have 10 reputation yet

Comment: So, upload it elsewhere and share the link. you can upload it on https://imgur.com/.

Comment: I have managed to fix the issue now, appreciate the help, sorry for being dumb

Comment: Hi Balakey Butlin, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following steps to check it :

1. Ensure that the function `rock_paper_scissors` is defined in the `rps8` module and that the function name is spelled correctly.
2. Check your python interpreter by shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Python: Select Interpreter".
3. Check your module name. Make sure that the module name `rps8` is correct. This should be the name of the Python file which you defined the function `rock_paper_scissors`.